# How to use database globally?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I installed apache, php, phpmyadmin, mysql on ubuntu 22.04 on VirtualBox, it works.
Problem is, I want to add something to databse fe. from school, running php code there, or other location - doesn't matter where, I just want to make this db accessible,  public?

And, i think while i want to add sth do this db from school, ubuntu must be running at home?

I know the php connection code, and i have had create user in phpmyadmin with all privileges.

Please help

I didn't try anything yet, becase i don't want to ruin the ubuntu configuration

Comment: Configure port forwarding on your router that forwards port 3306 to the IP of the virtualBox VM.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could open your MySQL Server port 3306 to the internet. But this is like leaving your keys in your car in a bad neighborhood. You should expect it to be hacked within *minutes*.

There are basically two options that are safer:

- You could use a VPN. Require that clients must use the same VPN to access your MySQL Server. That way there is no public network route to your MySQL Server.
- You could implement a public web service. This would allow clients to post requests via *https* to read or modify data in your MySQL Server. The MySQL Server should *not* be exposed to the internet, but it must be reachable by the web service. This is achieved by using routing and firewalls.

  Writing a web service means developing code to handle the requests and perform database queries. But the advantage is that because it's your code,  the web service only runs database queries you intend to be allowed. Beware of developing SQL injection vulnerabilities by accident.

Both of these solutions take some technical expertise. Putting your database on the wild internet is not something that should be attempted by amateurs.